# Fetching token from extension storage in React + Apollo GraphQL browser extension

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, graphql, apollo-client

I'm trying to create a browser extension using React and Apollo GraphQL. For background, I'm using the `webextension-polyfill` which is why I refer to the `browser` namespace as opposed to `chrome`.

In my `index.tsx` file, I try to set up my Apollo Client as follows:

```
// ... more imports ...
import App from './App'

const link = HttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:8000/graphql/',
});

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {

  window.postMessage({ type: "GET_TOKEN" }, "*");

  // I need to fetch `token` from the the result of the above postMessage
  
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `JWT ${token}` : "",
    }
  }
})

export const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(link),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Normally in a regular web app you'd store your token in localStorage, and fetch it from there like so `localStorage.getItem("token")`.

But since this is a browser extension, I can't use localStorage and fetch from it across all tabs. I have to use `browser.storage.local`.

I can successfully save to the extension's `browser.storage.local` after the user signs in, so you can assume the token is available and can be fetched.

Since you cannot interact with `browser.storage.local` outside of the context of the extension, I have to send a message to my `content.js` script to tell it to fetch it from storage.

This is why I have `window.postMessage({ type: "GET_TOKEN" }, "*");` above.

Then in my `content.js` file, I listen for the message, and send another message with the result:

```
window.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
   ...
   onDidReceiveMessage(event);
})

async function onDidReceiveMessage(event) {
   if (event.data.type && (event.data.type === "GET_TOKEN")) {
     const payload = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({ type: "TOKEN_RESULT", token: await browser.storage.local.get("token") }));
     window.postMessage(payload, "*");
   }
}
```

My problem is now listening for this event and using it in the `index.tsx` file during my setup of Apollo Client.

In the `index.tsx` file, I've tried something along the lines of:

```
const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {

  window.postMessage({ type: "GET_TOKEN" }, "*");

  window.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
    if (event.data.type && (event.data.type === "TOKEN_RESULT")) {
      token = event.data.token.token
    }
  });

  // the value of `event.data.token.token` in the listener is correct and successfully fetched
  // but can only really be used in the listener, I need it available to be used below
  // as part of this outer `setContext` for Apollo
  
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `JWT ${token}` : "",
    }
  }
})
```

How do I fetch the token out of storage in the context of a browser extension, if I need to use it in a setup up file like the one used to setup Apollo Client?

Any help or alternative approaches would be appreciated.

Comment: The problem is that all messaging is asynchronous so your last code snippet returns when `token` is still undefined. Usually it is solved by calling some setState analog in the event listener that receives the actual token value. P.S. Do you really need to access this data outside of extension context or is it a mistake in architecture? If it's intended then do you need it on all sites or only a few? If it's only a few then you can use [external messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage) directly.

Comment: Yeah typically I'd set the returned value in state which would trigger a rerender, but this is all before the app is mounted. Guess I'd need some way to rerender `ReactDOM.render(..)` when the listener eventually returns the value. And on your second question, yeah I need to access it on all sites otherwise I would have to ask the user to sign into the extension for each new domain they visit. And to do that I have to store it in the extension's `browser.storage.local` which you can only interact with outside the react app by sending messages (this is my current understanding).